# how to calculate the sum of medals per year in this dataframe?

Tags: r

For a presentation i want to do a data analysis about olympic medals vs GDP growth. i'm stuck at this point where i need to mutate the data. I want to calculate the total amount of medal per country per year. what function is best to use for this problem?

[image]

Comment: `medal %>% group_by(Country, Year) %>% count()`

Comment: Please post a reproducible example as R code instead of pictures.